# Plotly Scattermapbox: Is there a way to include some text above and below the markers?

Tags: python, plotly

In Plotly, using Scattermapbox, is there a way to display some text above and below the markers?

Currently the text only appears when I hover on the markers, and the plot shows only part of the text that I would like to display.

[image]

My input data frame `df_area` is as follows. I would like to display the text contained in both the `name` column and in the `forecast` column.

```
     name   latitude   longitude    forecast
 0   "AK"   2.675000   203.139000   "Cloudy"
 1   "Bd"   2.621000   203.224000   "Cloudy"
```

However, I can currently only display the text in the `forecast` column.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df_area["latitude"],
        lon=df_area["longitude"],
        mode="markers+text",
        marker={"size": 10},
        text=df_area["forecast"]))
```

Answer (score 6):

I included an example below, note that this requires a (free) mapbox access token.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

mapbox_access_token = 'your-free-token'

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['London', 'Oxford'],
                   'latitude': [51.509865, 51.7520],
                   'longitude': [-0.118092, -1.2577],
                   'forecast': ['Cloudy', 'Sunny']})

data = go.Scattermapbox(lat=list(df['latitude']),
                        lon=list(df['longitude']),
                        mode='markers+text',
                        marker=dict(size=20, color='green'),
                        textposition='top right',
                        textfont=dict(size=16, color='black'),
                        text=[df['name'][i] + '<br>' + df['forecast'][i] for i in range(df.shape[0])])

layout = dict(margin=dict(l=0, t=0, r=0, b=0, pad=0),
              mapbox=dict(accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                          center=dict(lat=51.6, lon=-0.2),
                          style='light',
                          zoom=8))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Comment: hi gflavia , I am trying to get your code to run on similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846672/plotly-scattermapbox-unable-to-add-text-to-markers can you check?